# How to Unit test deeply connected redux components?

Tags: unit-testing, redux

I tried to wrapped my component to test with a Provider and deep render it using react-test-renderer `renderer.create()`. In this case mapStateToProps works correctly but I don't get expected results with mapDispatchToProps. Here the component being tested renders other connected components.

My mapDispatchToProps looks something like

```
/* @flow */
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

import type { Dispatch } from './types';
import * as actions from './actions';

export default (dispatch: Dispatch, ownProps: Object): Object => ({
  actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch),
});
```

here the value of `actions` returned is `undefined`.

store.js

```
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux';
import { autoRehydrate } from 'redux-persist';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import rootReducer from './reducers';
import { REHYDRATE } from 'redux-persist/constants';

const store = compose(autoRehydrate(), applyMiddleware(thunk, createActionBuffer(REHYDRATE)))(createStore)(rootReducer);
```

export default store;